# compare a string with another string from a file c++

Tags: c++, ubuntu

I am trying to compare a string from `getline(file,line)` with a `std::string s="mmee"` :

```
if (line==s){}
```

but this is never executed. why?? inside the file i have:

```
mmee
hello
hey
```

How to trim the spaces or enter from string line?

Comment: Is the line in the file "mmee hello hey"? Because if it is I see no reason why the two strings should match.

Comment: How do you tell that a no-op is not executed?

Comment: What do you mean by "this is never executed"? you mean return false, didn't reach the line of code, runtime error.... what? Also did you try debugging?

Comment: Have you tried debugging by printing the strings to compare to the screen? Use `printf("'%s' == '%s'\n", line, s.c_str());` so that you will see any leading or trailing spaces. Also compare string lengths to make sure all characters are printable.

Comment: maybe you should post a minimal working sample of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct.

Please check your input file to verify there is no leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: i had some problems with some permissions

Answer (score 0):

First of all why do you think that will get executed.

as **mmee hello hey** is part of the same line in the file, when you do a **getline** line will contain the whole line and not just **mmee**. Hence the if condition would fail.

Look at this [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/863/) for trimming spaces.

Answer (score 0):

`std::getline()` by default reads to the first new-line character. You can specify the character to which you want the function to read, like this:

```
getline(file, line, ' ');  // not the space between single quote chars
```

This would read only "mmee" part of your example file (mmee hello hey).

EDIT: It is how I read your example. People who edited the OP just assumed that the input file is `mmee\nhello\nhey`

Comment: Reasonable assumption, the three words were all on separate lines, just not indented, so they were rendered on one line before the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the space by using

std::remove(astring.begin(), astring.end(), ' ');

and after that you can compare the string.

check out the link:: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/863/

You can compare to String : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/

Comment: (astring.begin(),astring.end(),' ') is there a space or no/

Comment: yes Their is a sapce ' '...Just check this link http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/863/